Compiling for iOS 15.0, but module 'WhisperKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 16.0
The error message:
Compiling for iOS 15.0, but module 'WhisperKit' has a minimum deployment target of iOS 16.0: /Users/saamer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/BeAwareConf-hbgkemigbbowvzhfaegoplloiayn/Index.noindex/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WhisperKit.swiftmodule/arm64-apple-ios.swiftmodule
I know this question has been asked a lot of times in the past but it doesn't seem like anyone has got a good answer for this. So I'm going to try to ask the question again, in case Apple created a solution for this problem.
For KhutbahCaptioning, I'd like to use the open source "WhisperKit" sdk for users who have the now iOS, and provide those users the new features with iOS 16 or newer. But don't want users who still use iOS 15 to not get other updates useful to them.
The error is ONLY on this line import WhisperKit, I know for SwiftCharts I was able to use canImport like this:
#if canImport(Charts)
import Charts
#endif

and that worked, but I'm getting the error above when I try to do that for WhisperKit. I tried all the solutions suggested in similar questions from the past, but none worked. Any one have success with this? Or are my only two options to set minimum deployment target to iOS 16 or don't use that library?

ALRIGHT, I was able to get the project to build! I don't know if there is or will be a better solution in the future. I didn't think my solution would work, so I wasn't too confident, but it took me about 4 hours to figure this out. It should take a lot lesser for you with these instructions
How I made the iOS 16 library build with iOS 15:
It was a really long process but I forked the WhisperKit repo and created my own, and added iOS 15 checks and changed the version requirements to iOS 15, as you can see in my commit history.
The problem was that it was dependent on another repo as well, luckily that was open source as well. So I forked it too and made similar changes, but my changes to the fork was not getting reflected and I learnt I needed to create a new release, which I learnt I could do by going to the repo in GitHub -> Go to the Code tab -> Tap on Tags -> Releases -> Draft a new release -> Choose a tag -> give a number higher.
And then reference this version & repo in the WhisperKit code Package resolved & swift files. And it worked, I am able to build successfully! Within my code, I added a check to make sure that the library code is used by iOS 16 devices and up
Tips
In order to figure out the changes needed quickly especially for big libraries, I recommend first focusing on changing iOS versions of your dependent packages just so you can add them to your project. And then it will show you which code lines have issues. I was able to "Show In Finder" for the problem files and open in a text editor, then Overwrite the Read-Only files to get rid of the errors one by one locally so the Xcode compiler could show me the other iOS 15 compatibility errors. And then once all were fixed, I copied those file changes to the actually open source package repositories I had created.
